# How extract an equivalent surface from a mesh after modify?

Tags: python, modifiers, topology, boolean-modifier, remesh

I have a mesh, lets call it Mesh1. I selected some faces on this mesh and extract them to create a new object. I'm interested on this surface (not a volume, just a surface), lets call this Mesh2.

Then I made a copy of Mesh1 and applied some modifiers (decimate, remesh, etc.). This will be Mesh3. Now, Mesh3 has a different topology compared to Mesh1 but both represent the same object with minimal differences in shape but with a (not so) different topology. Now, I want to use Mesh2 to find the equivalent area on Mesh3. I have tried different approaches but nothing works.

This process is part of a project with blender code in python, so I'm not interested on using a "manual" solution but something to be automatized. I was trying to use also shrinkwrap, but this only adapt mesh2 to the shape of mesh3. Any idea of how to do it?
[image]

Comment: What dos it mean to find the equivalent area on Mesh3? In what sense do you need to find it? How do you need to have it when it's found? Could you maybe describe the purpose of this so it's easier to understand the situation?

Comment: Could you use something like a [Sample Nearest Surface](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/modeling/geometry_nodes/mesh/sample/sample_nearest_surface.html) node to interpolate a boolean from Mesh2 to Mesh3 ?

Comment: I added an image. I want to extract the faces in mesh 3 that fall on the red area (mesh 2)

Comment: What sort of project is it? Why does it need to be purely Python? Technically, you can create Geometry Nodes modifier and all the nodes for it with Python. Would that be acceptable? What's the context of the situation? You could probably do that with bmesh as well, but we now have geometry nodes to make life easier with stuff like this. I mean if only automation is the goal, then you could reuse premade geometry nodes asset.

Comment: I'm creating an addon with several functions to unify and simplify a process through the Blender interface, this is one of the last steps. I already wrote a script to do this with Python and Trimesh libraries. However, importing those libraries to Blender could be complicated for the users of my addon.

Comment: Try modifiers: `Data Transfer`, `Vertex Weight Proximity`, `Geometry Proximity Node`/`Attribute Proximity` for Geometry Nodes or python utils: `mathutils.kdtree`, `mathutils.bvhtree`.